# How to pass the parameter to pundit policy

Tags: ruby-on-rails-6, pundit

I am using pundit right now.
But then in my controller, there is a search params with if condition, so I cannot simply use policy_scope to pass the pundit.

Posts_controller

```
  def index
    search = params['search']
    if search.present?
      @content = params['search']
      @posts = Post.joins(:user).where("users.content ILIKE ?", "%#{@content}%")
    else
      @posts = Post.all
    end
  end
```

Pundit

```
 def resolve
     scope.all
 end
```

I have try like @posts = PostPolicy::Scope.new(current_user, Post, @content).resolve , but it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Oh actually can do policy_scope(Post).joins(:user).where("users.content ILIKE ?", "%#{@content}%").